# Moving WSS sites to a new SharePoint 2010 Foundation server

Tags: sharepoint, upgrade, wss, wss-3.0

I posted this question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/296769/moving-wss-sites-to-a-new-sharepoint-2010-foundation-server) without responses so far, so I thought about asking here.
This [existing question](https://serverfault.com/questions/113714/wss3-0-to-sharepoint-foundation-2010-upgrade) helps but it doesn't answer all my questions.

I have WSS 3 running on Server1 (Server 2003) and its database is DBServer1 (SQL 2008). I have installed SharePoint 2010 Foundation on Server2 (Server 2008) with databases on DBServer2 (SQL 2008 R2).

SP 2010 Foundation is up and running ok and it already has one newly created Web Application. Now my goal is to copy all sites from Server1/DBServer1 to Server2/DBServer2 (and eventually retire Server1/DBServer1).

Could you please help me with a step-by-step list on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo there are ways you could migrate
1)in place upgrade see this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303307.aspx
2)Database attach with read-only databases
See this :http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2010/06/migrating-to-sharepoint-2010.html
Hope that helps